# App debugging showing non existing image path in the java code

Tags: android, adb, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

When debugging my app, it's currently returning a jpg file that I'm not able to see in my adb.

This is a screenshot from my IDE into debugging mode:

[image]

This is a screenshot from my adb shell console inside /storage/emulated/0/Pictures:

[image]

*Where is the **/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/JPEG_20170851311126_-1890481941.jpg** coming from?* Also, I noticed that every time the jpg image has the negative sign "126_**-**189" in the middle, the image is corrupted, so from my UI end, the image is empty.

Comment: please add your full source. and i have a question You mean that image is empty == image is null right?

Comment: I had to restart my emulator and then the problem was gone. I used:"adb shell stop
adb shell start